# ASP.NET Core MVC & Entity Framework Core: Fluent API relationship configuration wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I believe that I have my relationship between the Relationship and RelationshipType models wrong.

Basically I want to create a relationship for a contact with another contact, e.g. Contact1 has a relationship with Contact2 of type Employee for example. However, the foreign key for the Relationship/RelationshipType is in the RelationshipType table. Which doesn't make sense to me. When I create a relationship I want to assign the type in that Relationship  view/controller. Shouldn't I have a relationshipTypeId field in the relationship table so I can set that value there?

The way it is configured the relationshipTypeId is in the RelationshipType table. If I want to add a relationship, I have to update 2 tables.

Here is the `Contact` model class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; } = new HashSet<Relationship>();
}
```

Relationship model class:

```
public class Relationship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact? Parent { get; set; }
    public int? ChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact? Child { get; set; }
    public virtual RelationshipType? RelationshipType { get; set; }
}
```

`RelationshipType` model class:

```
public class RelationshipType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Type { get; set; }
    public int? RelationshipId { get; set; }
    public virtual Relationship? Relationship { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API

```
// Relationship configuration  
modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>(b =>
        {
            b.HasOne(r => r.Parent)
                .WithMany(c => c.Relationships)
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.ParentId);

            b.HasOne(r => r.Child)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.ChildId);

            b.HasOne(r => r.RelationshipType)
                .WithOne(rt => rt.Relationship)
                .HasForeignKey<RelationshipType>(rt => rt.RelationshipId);
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The database access and thus the configuration of the entities and their relationships is part of **Entity Framework Core** - not ASP.NET Core MVC (that's the **web stack** and has absolutely nothing to do with configuring and accessing your data)

Comment: Are you doing database-first or code-first?

Comment: In my opinion it should be a one-to-may relationship between RelationshipType and Relationship

Comment: I'm doing code first

Comment: @Ruikai Feng - I think you are right. And that made me realize that I think I can accomplish that with the navigation properties, and don't need the Fluent API. Does that sound right?

Comment: I am getting this error:  `   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Cannot create a relationship between 'Contact.Relationships' and 'Relationship.Child' because a relationship already exists between 'Contact.Relationships' and 'Relationship.Parent'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Relationship.Child' first in 'OnModelCreating'.